# Invalid enviroment variabels when using the t3 tech stack and trying to add record using prisma

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm making a an app using the t3 tech stack and want to use NextAuth and use their CredentialProvider, but when i go to register a user and push the user info to the DB using prisma i only get the error `Error: Invalid environment variables` and in the console I can see the error below. However when i go to sign in a user using any other provider such as github the enviroment variabels are available. I might have missed something in my code since I'm still very new to NextJS and Prisma so it would be great if i could get a second opinion on this.

```
Invalid environment variables:
 DATABASE_URL: Required
 NODE_ENV: Required
 NEXTAUTH_SECRET: Required
 NEXTAUTH_URL: Required
 DISCORD_CLIENT_ID: Required
 DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET: Required
 GOOGLE_ID: Required
 GOOGLE_SECRET: Required
 ID_GITHUB: Required
 SECRET_GITHUB: Required
 EMAIL_SERVER_USER: Required
 EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD: Required
 EMAIL_SERVER_HOST: Required
 EMAIL_SERVER_PORT: Required
 EMAIL_FROM: Required
```

My the full source code is available on my GitHub but the code that is causing the error right now is this

```js
async function handelRegister(values) {
  // TODO: Setup password hasing
  const password = values.password
  const valid_password = values.validPassword
  if (password === valid_password) {
    const curr_user_email = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        email: values.email,
      },
    })
    alert(curr_user_email)
    console.log(curr_user_email)
    if (curr_user_email) {
      alert('test')
      return null
    }
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        name: values.name,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
      },
    })
    console.log(user)
    alert(user)
    return user
  }
}
```

The link to the GitHub repo https://github.com/Retrokiller543/Blog-app-t3/tree/Dev.
Where i need the DB connection to save a user is currently in pages/account/register but this will be moved to an api later but right now i just need it to work for a prototype.

Comment: It looks like you're calling the `handelRegister` function from the client-side (from a form). By default, and for security reasons, environment variables in Next.js are not exposed to the browser. To expose an environment variable you have to add the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to the variable name. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Now all i need to figure ut is if theres anything else nextauth needs to log the user in. XD